# Python: how to ignore 'substring not found' error

Tags: python, string, substring

Let's say that you have a string array '`x`', containing very long strings, and you want to search for the following substring: "string.str", within each string in array `x`.

In the **vast majority** of the elements of `x`, the substring in question will be in the array element. However, maybe once or twice, it won't be. If it's not, then...

1) is there a way to just ignore the case and then move onto the next element of `x`, by using an `if` statement?

2) is there a way to do it without an `if` statement, in the case where you have many different substrings that you're looking for in any particular element of `x`, where you might potentially end up writing tons of `if` statements?

Comment: Second question - are you only interested if any of the substrings are contained in elements of x?  Or will you process the elements in x differently depending on which substring it contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `try` and `except` block. Here is a simplified example:

```
a = 'hello'
try:
    print a[6:]
except:
    pass
```

#### Expanded example:

```
a = ['hello', 'hi', 'hey', 'nice']
for i in a:
    try:
        print i[3:]
    except:
        pass

lo
e
```

Comment: will this automatically take you all the way back up to the beginning of the for loop, ignoring anything after the try-except block?

Comment: @simply_helpful. What do you mean?

Comment: if "except" becomes activated, what's the very next statement that the program will run?

Comment: @simply_helpful, It will just `pass` if except gets activated and then it will move on with the rest of code that comes after these blocks.

Comment: @simply_helpful, provided expanded example

Comment: That was really helpful! As a last note, is it possible to make it only catch the exception whenever there is a substring-is-not-found error? What if for any other error, it really *should* stop the program??

Comment: @simply_helpful, Sure! If you get an IndexError for example, you can do: `except IndexError:` and then your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter the list concisely:

Filter by length:

```
a_list = ["1234", "12345", "123456", "123"]
print [elem[3:] for elem in a_list if len(elem) > 3]
>>> ['4', '45', '456']
```

Filter by substring:

```
a_list = ["1234", "12345", "123456", "123"]
a_substring = "456"
print [elem for elem in a_list if a_substring in elem]
>>> ['123456']
```

Filter by multiple substrings (Checks if all the substrings are in the element by comparing the [filtered](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) array size and the number of substrings):

```
a_list = ["1234", "12345", "123456", "123", "56", "23"]
substrings = ["56","23"]
print [elem for elem in a_list if\
             len(filter(lambda x: x in elem, substrings)) == len(substrings)]
>>> ['123456']
```

Comment: I have to say that I think your naming convention is really confusing. Using `_` as variable name when actually using that variable for something is not how it usually is used. Usually `_` is used for variables that do not matter (for example unboxing a tuple while only being interested in the first: `a, _ = tpl`

Comment: Thanks. Changed _ to elem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand what you wrote, you can use the `continue` keyword to jump to the next element in the array.

```
elements = ["Victor", "Victor123", "Abcdefgh", "123456", "1234"]
astring = "Victor"

for element in elements:
  if astring in element:
    # do stuff
  else:
   continue # this is useless, but do what you want, buy without it the code works fine too.
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Use `any()` to see if any of the substrings are in an item of `x`.  `any()` will consume a generator expression and it exhibits *short circuit* beavior - it will return `True` with the first expression that evaluates to `True` and stop *consuming* the generator.

```
>>> substrings = ['list', 'of', 'sub', 'strings']
>>> x = ['list one', 'twofer', 'foo sub', 'two dollar pints', 'yard of hoppy poppy']
>>> for item in x:
    if any(sub in item.split() for sub in substrings):
        print item


list one
foo sub
yard of hoppy poppy
>>>
```